# High CPU utilization showing in CPU

Tags: top, cpu-usage, high-availability

We are running Two Node cluster using Redhat Pacemaker running on RHEL 7. Last thursday (3/2/2022) i updated kernel to latest version. And on Friday at 3:49 First node rebooted(Reason unknow)  and then rejoined but at time resources were running on Node2.

Today i noticed that are is high cpu utilization and top command shows

```
%Cpu(s):  2.9 us, 89.8 sy,  0.2 ni,  7.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

I dont know what process is using 89.8% of cpu

## top command

```
top - 07:10:55 up 4 days, 14:17,  2 users,  load average: 8.08, 8.13, 7.98
Tasks: 483 total,   8 running, 475 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.7 us, 89.7 sy,  0.2 ni,  7.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 39464316+total,  1881036 free, 21074576+used, 18201638+buff/cache
KiB Swap: 93749248 total, 93749248 free,        0 used. 18109798+avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
183327 oracle    20   0  195.5g  56260  42096 R  99.3  0.0   1133:15 oracle_183327_s
183552 oracle    20   0  195.5g  58704  42032 R  99.3  0.0   5626:11 oracle_183552_s
183443 oracle    20   0  195.5g  54488  40728 R  98.8  0.0   1626:54 oracle_183443_s
183554 oracle    20   0  195.5g  57076  41912 R  98.6  0.0   5304:10 oracle_183554_s
183354 oracle    20   0  195.5g  47248  39176 R  97.8  0.0   4847:28 oracle_183354_s
183556 oracle    20   0  195.5g  60040  43456 R  97.8  0.0   2486:30 oracle_183556_s
104734 oracle    20   0  195.5g  48516  39564 R  97.1  0.0   1583:06 oracle_104734_s
142910 root      20   0  162524   2704   1588 R  27.5  0.0   1:43.11 top
  4612 root      39  19   13172   9268    480 S   3.8  0.0 255:12.73 apps.plugin
  3918 netdata   39  19  251412 137752   2760 S   1.0  0.0  92:52.38 netdata
175736 root      20   0  755216  74556  13932 S   1.0  0.0  64:27.23 guard_stap
183545 oracle    20   0  195.5g  61516  42944 S   1.0  0.0  50:46.33 oracle_183545_s
165271 oracle    -2   0  195.4g  18936  15872 S   0.7  0.0  44:31.74 ora_vktm_ssys
183352 oracle    20   0  195.5g  45884  38572 S   0.7  0.0  35:28.20 oracle_183352_s
183550 oracle    20   0  195.5g  52640  42520 S   0.7  0.0  47:01.94 oracle_183550_s
189069 oracle    20   0  195.5g  58344  41844 S   0.7  0.0  38:45.02 oracle_189069_s
  3695 root      20   0  916256 131244  18368 S   0.5  0.0  42:22.64 ds_agent
  3721 root      rt   0  196440  98180  70968 S   0.5  0.0  42:39.31 corosync
 69846 oracle    20   0  195.5g  49116  39316 S   0.5  0.0  10:22.26 oracle_69846_ss
183350 oracle    20   0  195.5g  45672  38332 S   0.5  0.0  36:46.71 oracle_183350_s
183356 oracle    20   0  195.5g  45992  38452 S   0.5  0.0  36:24.67 oracle_183356_s
183787 oracle    20   0  195.5g  45428  37976 S   0.5  0.0   2:10.28 oracle_183787_s
198328 oracle    20   0  195.5g  52616  42012 S   0.5  0.0  38:30.80 oracle_198328_s
  1471 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.2  0.0   0:14.07 MpxPeriodicCall
  3822 root      20   0  138468   9392   5696 S   0.2  0.0   4:15.32 stonithd
  3962 swiagent  20   0 2342756  14444   6624 S   0.2  0.0   5:07.94 swiagent
  4607 netdata   39  19  161488  21948   4312 S   0.2  0.0  16:25.79 python
 22089 oracle    20   0  195.4g  26088  21472 S   0.2  0.0   0:01.55 ora_m006_ssys
114147 oracle    20   0  195.4g  41528  34804 S   0.2  0.0   0:00.43 oracle_114147_s
117437 oracle    20   0  195.5g  45332  38108 S   0.2  0.0   5:33.05 oracle_117437_s
135186 root      20   0 3706316 163948  31820 S   0.2  0.0  18:33.37 ds_am
148697 netdata   39  19    1648   1008    616 S   0.2  0.0   0:00.20 bash
152754 root      20   0  477760   4984   3960 S   0.2  0.0   0:00.01 SolarWinds.ADM.
165327 oracle    20   0  195.5g  81356  51292 S   0.2  0.0   1:49.24 ora_mmon_ssys
183783 oracle    20   0  195.5g  44960  37616 S   0.2  0.0   2:12.17 oracle_183783_s
     1 root      20   0  191832   4924   2660 S   0.0  0.0  44:03.90 systemd
     2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.13 kthreadd
     4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
     6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:26.87 ksoftirqd/0
     7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.91 migration/0
     8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
     9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  10:48.66 rcu_sched
    10 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lru-add-drain
    11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.62 watchdog/0
```

This CPU utilization is increasing since Friday 9AM and was gradually increasing

## SAR command (Friday)

```
sudo sar -u  ALL -f /var/log/sa/sa04
Linux 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64 (prod-db2-node2)      02/04/2022      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest    %gnice     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      3.54      0.31      2.99      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.10
12:20:01 AM     all      3.56      0.31      3.00      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.08
12:30:01 AM     all      3.55      0.31      3.04      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.04
12:40:01 AM     all      3.62      0.31      3.06      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.96
12:50:01 AM     all      3.53      0.31      3.34      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.76
01:00:01 AM     all      3.74      0.31      3.08      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.81
01:10:01 AM     all      3.88      0.31      3.07      0.08      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     92.64
01:20:01 AM     all      3.54      0.31      3.02      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.08
01:30:01 AM     all      3.56      0.31      3.04      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     93.03
01:40:01 AM     all      3.55      0.30      3.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.07
01:50:01 AM     all      3.61      0.31      3.04      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.99
02:00:01 AM     all      3.55      0.31      3.05      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.03
02:10:01 AM     all      3.60      0.31      3.04      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.99
02:20:01 AM     all      3.52      0.31      3.01      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.10
02:30:01 AM     all      3.75      0.31      3.05      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.83
02:40:01 AM     all      3.52      0.31      3.01      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.11
02:50:01 AM     all      3.57      0.31      3.02      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.04
03:00:01 AM     all      3.55      0.30      3.02      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.08
03:10:01 AM     all      3.59      0.31      3.03      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.00
03:20:01 AM     all      3.58      0.31      3.04      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.02
03:30:01 AM     all      3.51      0.31      2.99      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.13
03:40:01 AM     all      3.57      0.31      3.02      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.05
03:50:01 AM     all      3.55      0.34      3.10      0.20      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.79
04:00:01 AM     all      3.71      0.31      3.04      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.89
04:10:01 AM     all      3.54      0.31      3.01      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.08
04:20:01 AM     all      3.53      0.31      3.02      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.08
04:30:01 AM     all      3.51      0.31      3.01      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.12
04:40:01 AM     all      3.57      0.31      3.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     93.03
04:50:01 AM     all      3.45      0.31      3.19      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     93.00
05:00:01 AM     all      3.57      0.31      3.05      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.01
05:10:02 AM     all      3.56      0.31      3.07      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.00
05:20:01 AM     all      3.54      0.31      3.09      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.01
05:30:01 AM     all      3.72      0.31      3.08      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.83
05:40:01 AM     all      3.54      0.31      3.05      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.05
05:50:01 AM     all      3.53      0.31      3.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.08
06:00:01 AM     all      3.53      0.31      3.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     93.08
06:10:01 AM     all      3.61      0.31      3.06      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.97
06:20:01 AM     all      3.50      0.31      3.01      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.13

06:20:01 AM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest    %gnice     %idle
06:30:01 AM     all      3.58      0.31      3.09      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     92.97
06:40:01 AM     all      3.56      0.31      3.06      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     93.01
06:50:01 AM     all      3.56      0.31      3.07      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     93.00
07:00:02 AM     all      3.70      0.31      3.09      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     92.85
07:10:01 AM     all      3.61      0.31      3.09      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     92.93
07:20:02 AM     all      3.50      0.31      3.07      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.07
07:30:01 AM     all      3.59      0.30      3.08      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     92.97
07:40:01 AM     all      3.58      0.31      3.09      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     92.96
07:50:01 AM     all      3.54      0.31      3.06      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.04
08:00:01 AM     all      3.55      0.31      3.26      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.82
08:10:01 AM     all      3.57      0.31      3.07      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.00
08:20:01 AM     all      3.55      0.31      3.08      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.01
08:30:01 AM     all      3.69      0.31      3.11      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.84
08:40:01 AM     all      3.62      0.31      3.11      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     92.91
08:50:01 AM     all      3.52      0.31      3.06      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.02      0.00      0.00     93.06
09:00:01 AM     all      3.28      0.29     15.20      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.16
09:10:01 AM     all      3.28      0.29     15.30      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.07
09:20:01 AM     all      3.26      0.29     15.33      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.06
09:30:01 AM     all      3.23      0.29     15.30      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.12
09:40:01 AM     all      3.30      0.28     15.32      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.03
09:50:01 AM     all      3.26      0.28     15.29      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.10
10:00:01 AM     all      3.38      0.28     15.37      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.90
10:10:01 AM     all      3.31      0.28     15.33      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.01
10:20:01 AM     all      3.23      0.29     15.33      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.09
10:30:01 AM     all      3.28      0.28     15.33      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.04
10:40:01 AM     all      3.25      0.29     15.31      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.09
10:50:01 AM     all      3.27      0.28     15.33      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.05
11:00:01 AM     all      3.21      0.28     15.32      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.12
11:10:01 AM     all      3.33      0.29     15.35      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.96
11:20:01 AM     all      3.26      0.28     15.32      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.06
11:30:01 AM     all      3.44      0.28     15.36      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.85
11:40:01 AM     all      3.26      0.29     15.32      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     81.07
11:50:01 AM     all      3.29      0.29     15.33      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.02
12:00:01 PM     all      3.29      0.28     15.33      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.02
12:10:01 PM     all      3.29      0.29     15.35      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.01
12:20:01 PM     all      3.27      0.28     15.35      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.02
12:30:01 PM     all      3.25      0.29     15.34      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.06
12:40:01 PM     all      3.30      0.28     15.35      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     80.99

12:40:01 PM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest    %gnice     %idle
12:50:01 PM     all      3.25      0.28     15.34      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.06
01:00:01 PM     all      3.46      0.29     15.40      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.79
01:10:01 PM     all      3.25      0.29     15.34      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.05
01:20:01 PM     all      3.30      0.28     15.38      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.98
01:30:01 PM     all      3.26      0.28     15.36      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.03
01:40:01 PM     all      3.61      0.29     15.41      0.18      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.47
01:50:01 PM     all      3.24      0.28     15.38      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     81.03
02:00:01 PM     all      3.29      0.28     15.39      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.97
02:10:01 PM     all      3.30      0.28     15.38      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     80.96
02:20:01 PM     all      3.14      0.28     20.19      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     76.32
02:30:02 PM     all      3.22      0.28     27.71      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.73
02:40:01 PM     all      3.00      0.28     27.66      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.99
02:50:01 PM     all      3.06      0.28     27.65      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.94
03:00:01 PM     all      3.00      0.28     27.68      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.97
03:10:02 PM     all      3.28      0.27     27.70      0.05      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.66
03:20:01 PM     all      2.99      0.28     27.66      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     69.00
03:30:01 PM     all      3.07      0.28     27.68      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.90
03:40:01 PM     all      3.04      0.28     27.67      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.94
03:50:01 PM     all      3.04      0.27     27.69      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.93
04:00:01 PM     all      3.19      0.28     27.71      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.76
04:10:01 PM     all      3.09      0.28     28.14      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.42
04:20:01 PM     all      3.04      0.28     27.69      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.92
04:30:01 PM     all      3.04      0.28     27.68      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.94
04:40:01 PM     all      3.08      0.28     27.72      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.85
04:50:01 PM     all      3.01      0.28     27.70      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.95
05:00:01 PM     all      3.05      0.28     27.68      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.92
05:10:01 PM     all      5.55      0.26     32.05      6.84      0.00      0.00      0.12      0.00      0.00     55.17
05:20:01 PM     all      3.05      0.28     27.71      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.89
05:30:01 PM     all      3.19      0.28     27.73      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.73
05:40:01 PM     all      3.05      0.28     27.70      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.91
05:50:01 PM     all      3.03      0.28     27.69      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.93
06:00:01 PM     all      3.03      0.28     27.72      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.91
06:10:02 PM     all      3.06      0.28     27.72      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.88
06:20:01 PM     all      3.07      0.28     27.72      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.87
06:30:01 PM     all      3.09      0.28     27.77      0.56      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.26
06:40:01 PM     all      3.05      0.28     27.74      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.86
06:50:01 PM     all      3.07      0.28     27.71      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.87
07:00:01 PM     all      3.19      0.28     27.75      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.71

07:00:01 PM     CPU      %usr     %nice      %sys   %iowait    %steal      %irq     %soft    %guest    %gnice     %idle
07:10:01 PM     all      3.14      0.27     27.76      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.76
07:20:01 PM     all      3.03      0.28     27.72      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.90
07:30:01 PM     all      3.08      0.28     27.73      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.84
07:40:01 PM     all      3.06      0.28     27.73      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.87
07:50:01 PM     all      3.05      0.28     27.73      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.87
08:00:01 PM     all      3.03      0.27     27.74      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.89
08:10:01 PM     all      3.10      0.27     27.76      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.79
08:20:01 PM     all      3.03      0.28     27.73      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.90
08:30:01 PM     all      3.23      0.28     27.77      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.66
08:40:01 PM     all      3.08      0.28     27.75      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.82
08:50:01 PM     all      3.04      0.28     27.74      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.88
09:00:01 PM     all      3.08      0.28     27.76      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.81
09:10:01 PM     all      3.07      0.28     27.77      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.81
09:20:01 PM     all      3.07      0.28     27.76      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.81
09:30:01 PM     all      3.04      0.28     27.74      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.87
09:40:01 PM     all      3.09      0.28     27.77      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     68.79
09:50:01 PM     all      3.04      0.28     27.77      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     68.85
10:00:01 PM     all      3.21      0.26     36.38      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     60.08
10:10:01 PM     all      7.59      0.25     40.00      0.15      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     51.98
10:20:01 PM     all      2.98      0.26     40.02      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.68
10:30:01 PM     all      2.98      0.25     40.02      0.04      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.67
10:40:01 PM     all      3.00      0.25     40.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.65
10:50:01 PM     all      2.97      0.26     40.05      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.65
11:00:01 PM     all      2.92      0.26     40.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.04      0.00      0.00     56.72
11:10:01 PM     all      3.03      0.25     40.08      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.57
11:20:01 PM     all      2.95      0.26     40.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.70
11:30:01 PM     all      3.14      0.26     40.06      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.47
11:40:01 PM     all      2.97      0.26     40.05      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.67
11:50:01 PM     all      2.99      0.26     40.06      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     56.63
Average:        all      3.36      0.29     16.80      0.09      0.00      0.00      0.03      0.00      0.00     79.43
```

It started increase exactly at nine AM on Friday

## SAR command (Latest)

```
sudo sar -u
Linux 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64 (prod-db2-node2)      02/08/2022      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:02 AM     all      1.54      0.21     88.00      0.02      0.00     10.23
12:20:01 AM     all      1.50      0.22     87.99      0.01      0.00     10.28
12:30:01 AM     all      1.47      0.21     87.97      0.01      0.00     10.34
12:40:01 AM     all      1.48      0.22     87.98      0.01      0.00     10.31
12:50:01 AM     all      1.47      0.21     88.00      0.01      0.00     10.30
01:00:01 AM     all      1.70      0.22     87.98      0.01      0.00     10.10
01:10:01 AM     all      1.93      0.21     87.94      0.02      0.00      9.90
01:20:01 AM     all      1.50      0.22     88.00      0.01      0.00     10.27
01:30:02 AM     all      1.51      0.21     87.97      0.01      0.00     10.29
01:40:01 AM     all      1.51      0.21     87.95      0.01      0.00     10.32
01:50:01 AM     all      1.46      0.21     87.96      0.02      0.00     10.35
02:00:02 AM     all      1.49      0.22     87.95      0.01      0.00     10.32
02:10:02 AM     all      1.53      0.22     87.93      0.01      0.00     10.31
02:20:02 AM     all      1.44      0.22     87.95      0.01      0.00     10.38
02:30:01 AM     all      1.70      0.21     87.94      0.02      0.00     10.13
02:40:01 AM     all      1.44      0.21     87.95      0.02      0.00     10.38
02:50:01 AM     all      1.47      0.21     87.97      0.01      0.00     10.34
03:00:02 AM     all      1.43      0.21     87.94      0.01      0.00     10.40
03:10:01 AM     all      1.50      0.21     87.96      0.01      0.00     10.31
03:20:01 AM     all      1.51      0.23     87.97      0.01      0.00     10.28
03:30:02 AM     all      1.48      0.21     87.93      0.01      0.00     10.36
03:40:02 AM     all      1.47      0.22     87.94      0.02      0.00     10.35
03:50:01 AM     all      1.44      0.22     87.95      0.01      0.00     10.38
04:00:01 AM     all      1.64      0.21     87.94      0.02      0.00     10.19
04:10:01 AM     all      1.52      0.22     87.92      0.02      0.00     10.33
04:20:01 AM     all      1.45      0.22     87.92      0.02      0.00     10.40
04:30:02 AM     all      1.43      0.21     87.95      0.02      0.00     10.39
04:40:02 AM     all      1.48      0.22     87.95      0.02      0.00     10.33
04:50:01 AM     all      1.41      0.22     87.97      0.02      0.00     10.39
05:00:01 AM     all      1.48      0.22     87.94      0.02      0.00     10.35
05:10:01 AM     all      1.53      0.21     87.95      0.02      0.00     10.29
05:20:01 AM     all      1.45      0.22     87.96      0.01      0.00     10.36
05:30:02 AM     all      1.65      0.21     87.92      0.01      0.00     10.20
05:40:01 AM     all      1.49      0.21     87.94      0.01      0.00     10.35
05:50:01 AM     all      1.43      0.21     87.95      0.01      0.00     10.40
06:00:01 AM     all      1.47      0.21     87.93      0.01      0.00     10.38
06:10:01 AM     all      1.50      0.22     87.94      0.01      0.00     10.34
06:20:01 AM     all      1.44      0.22     87.96      0.01      0.00     10.38
06:30:01 AM     all      1.47      0.21     87.93      0.01      0.00     10.37
06:40:01 AM     all      1.43      0.21     87.94      0.01      0.00     10.40
06:50:01 AM     all      1.44      0.22     87.94      0.01      0.00     10.39
07:00:01 AM     all      1.75      0.22     88.04      0.01      0.00      9.98
07:10:01 AM     all      2.27      0.21     88.86      0.01      0.00      8.65
Average:        all      1.53      0.21     87.98      0.01      0.00     10.27
```

## VMSTAT Command

```
vmstat 1 -w
procs -----------------------memory---------------------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- --------cpu--------
 r  b         swpd         free         buff        cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs  us  sy  id  wa  st
 7  0            0      4380564       827180    179070080    0    0   231    41   11    9   3  48  48   0   0
 7  0            0      4364796       827180    179070080    0    0     0   160 9274 3727   1  88  10   0   0
 7  0            0      4359876       827184    179070080    0    0     0   176 9180 3915   1  88  11   0   0
 7  0            0      4359372       827184    179070096    0    0  1664    36 9201 3607   1  88  11   0   0
 7  0            0      4351796       827184    179070112    0    0  6656   156 9392 4170   1  89  10   0   0
 7  0            0      4361172       827184    179070096    0    0  1664   208 9352 4380   1  89  10   0   0
 7  0            0      4360752       827184    179070096    0    0     0    48 9179 3496   0  88  12   0   0
 7  0            0      4362452       827184    179070096    0    0     0    12 9281 4572   1  89   9   0   0
 7  0            0      4363568       827184    179070096    0    0     0   124 9197 3497   0  88  12   0   0
 8  0            0      4364952       827184    179070096    0    0     0   140 9189 3682   0  88  11   0   0
 7  0            0      4364640       827184    179070096    0    0     0    88 9195 3556   0  88  12   0   0
```

I checked for the logs and there nothing i could find that could cause the high cpu utilization

Now i know that TOP command is showing processes are related to Oracle DB. But Category shows that 89.8 in SystemSpace and not in UserSpace.

Any advice on how to get what caused this spike

Thanks

Comment: So because the high cpu usage by the oracle processes are spent in `system`, you are not going to investigate those processes? Really?

Comment: Are you implying something or just mocking. Is this how the StackExchange works , If you  are saying to check oracle processes then yes i already checked there are some big sql queries but i'm confused "Why system space is utilizing high cpu" or is it really is oracle processes

Comment: It's clear the oracle processes are responsible for it, quite possibly one or more kernel threads have been created to handle what oracle wants. If there are big sql queries going on, then I would expect large system usage.

Comment: And one thing that is missing, is the number of context swiches which can be had from vmstat. I assume this will show the oracle processes making large number of syscalls such as malloc.

Comment: So on Tuesday i restarted the Nodes and all became normal, now cluster is working normally